# foxCSS3:How to flip the card horizontally on hover?

Tags: css, animation

I have created a css3 animation, which animate on hover. But the horizontal flip is not working correctly when i hover it keeps moving around and doest seem to repond correctly on hover either. How can i fix  this?
It doest work on chrome for me and on firefox when it switched to 8 it moves

[JSFiddele](http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/6Lur2/)

```
<style type="Text/css">
       .container {
      width: 200px;
      height: 260px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto 10px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      -webkit-perspective: 800px;
         -moz-perspective: 800px;
           -o-perspective: 800px;
              perspective: 800px;
    }

    #card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
         -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
           -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
              transition: transform 1s;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
           -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
              transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    #card.flipped {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
              transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    }

    #card figure {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 260px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 140px;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
         -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
           -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
              backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    #card .front {
      background: red;

    }

    #card .back {
      background: blue;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
              transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    }
#card:hover {
transform:rotateY(180deg);  

}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<section class="container">
<div id="card">
<figure class="front">7</figure>
<figure class="back">8</figure>
</div>
</section>

</body>
```

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: your code works very well for me on chrome. responds well and only flips without moving around. please be more specific as to what doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

This solution is taken from the blog of David Walsh i hope it can you help you
Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/hgbmC/)
[Blog page](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)

```
<div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                front
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                back
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `margin: 0` to your `#card`

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lur2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

please replace this `.container` class with

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

I think after do that this will work fine, no need to add "perspective" property.